# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'

Tags: python, django, docker-compose

I'm writing project using docker and django (2.1).
I've installed module 'django-widget-tweaks' inside a container and added 'widget_tweaks' to `INSTALLED_APPS`. When I start project using `docker-compose up` everything works well, but when I want to run something like `docker-compose run <container name> python manage.py test` in another terminal an error occurs.

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'widget_tweaks'
```

But when I directly run the same command `python manage.py test` inside a docker container, it works. widget-tweaks has been installed both on container and on my machine. Could you advice something to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you run `docker-compose exec <container name> python -m site` and compare that to `python -m site` run directly from inside the container? The two should have the same value for `site-packages`

Comment: Yes, they are. This is the output:
sys.path = [
    '/src',
    '/usr/local/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True

Comment: OK. Could you also do the same, but with `docker-compose exec <container name> python -m pip show django-widget-tweaks` and `python -m pip show django-widget-tweaks` from inside the container?

Comment: Both have the same output again: Name: django-widget-tweaks
Version: 1.4.2
Summary: Tweak the form field rendering in templates, not in python-level form definitions.
Home-page: https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks
Author: Mikhail Korobov
Author-email: kmike84@gmail.com
License: MIT license
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: